# Parent-child hierarchy

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a 2 tables in database: `Person` and `child`.
They are hierarchy it means my child table has an Id that is PRIMARY KEY but not auto incremental.this Id fill by Id of Parent table

I have created a EDMX from these
but when I want to save a child I can't see the fields of parent in my child class
in EF it's not supported?

I want to do it like in NHIBERNATE.
please help me - what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shoud just write something like

```
ChildInstance.Parent = ParentInstance;
```

By this assignment you set the necessary relationship explicitly. You don't need to assign key properties manually in EF.